# Issue with AWS Instance Scheduler Schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduler

Having an issue with AWS Instance schedule.

Im trying to shutdown Instances at 2am and start them up at 8am Mon-Fri.

When i tried to do this with one Period, i get the following error:
ERROR : Begin time 08:00:00 must be earlier than end time in 02:00:00

Is there any way around this? Help would be great.

Comment: I think one work around is, have 2 schedules. One deals with start another deals with stop. Though this looks like promotion, I would say try INVOKE cloud (http://invoke.cloud), which handles scenarios like these very easily. Disclaimer: I am co-founder.

Comment: create 2 periods, one with daily shutdown at 2 AM and other with 8 AM startup mon-fri. Then create a schedule and include these periods. Period.

Comment: So i tried this last night, nothing shutdown or started up. When i check DynomoDB State Table , i see all the tagged instance ID's with a state of "any". Any idea why this could be happening?Example of my schedule and periods: "schedule","office-hours","Office hours",,,,"{ ""office-hours-start"", ""office-hours-stop"" } ","US/Eastern" "period","office-hours-start","Office hours start","{ ""mon-fri"" } ","08:00",,, "period","office-hours-stop","Office hours stop","{ ""mon-fri"" } ",,"02:00",,

Answer (score 1):

Based on [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/instance-scheduler/components.html):

*The begintime and endtime fields define when the Instance Scheduler will start and stop instances. If you specify a start time only, the instance must be stopped manually. Similarly, if you specify a stop time only, the instance must be started manually. If you don’t specify either time, the solution uses the days of the week, days of the month, or months rules to start and stop instances.*

One way to solve your problem is, define two periods to a schedule. One for start and another for Stop (or) Use 3rd part solutions like [INVOKE Cloud](http://invoke.cloud). Disclaimer:- I am co-founder

Comment: hmm, you cant assign two schedules. Do you mean Periods? I will try and assign those two periods to the Schedule.

Comment: So i tried this last night, nothing shutdown or started up. When i check DynomoDB State Table , i see all the tagged instance ID's with a state of "any". Any idea why this could be happening?Example of my schedule and periods:

"schedule","office-hours","Office hours",,,,"{ ""office-hours-start"", ""office-hours-stop"" } ","US/Eastern"
"period","office-hours-start","Office hours start","{ ""mon-fri"" } ","08:00",,,
"period","office-hours-stop","Office hours stop","{ ""mon-fri"" } ",,"02:00",,

Comment: I never heard of state "any" and couldn't find any references of this state in documentation too.

Comment: DEBUG : Checking conditions for period "office-hours-start-test"
DEBUG : [running] Time 10:50:20 is before starttime 11:00:00, returned state is any
 DEBUG : Checking conditions for period "office-hours-stop-test"
DEBUG : [running] Weekday "fri" in weekdays (mon-fri)
DEBUG : [stopped] Time 10:50:20 is after stoptime 10:40:00, returned state is stopped
 DEBUG : "Any" state period found for current time in schedule "office-hours-test", desired state is any
DEBUG : Desired state for instance from schedule "office-hours-test" is any, last desired state was any, actual state is running

Comment: Can you try by just having either start (or) stop and see if it is working fine or not?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have two periods. One period begintime is `00:00` and endtime `02:00`. The other period begintime `08:00` and endtime `23:59`. Add them to the same schedule in the periods StringSet.

**Note**:
The scheduler will not try to stop the instance at `23:59` and try to start it at `00:00` because by default the scheduler "checks the state of each instance at five minute intervals which means the solution will perform start and stop actions every five minutes" as seen in the [facts](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/instance-scheduler/). The scheduler skips over the first period endtime as the second period's begintime has already begun.